# Unable to add Top and Bottom Borders

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet which currently generates a set of data when the sheet is open but I want to add top and bottom borders to these rows as they generate. I'm unfortunately not sure how to add in I thought it was the below but this just errors advising it's not a valid parameter.

I thought it might just be this:

```
   With InputWorksheet                                                                                  ' Set the worksheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A" & row_ptr), Address:="", SubAddress:=AddStr, TextToDisplay:=DataSourceWorksheet.Range("O" & i).Value
        .Borders (xlEdgeTop), LineStyle = xlContinuous, ColorIndex = 0, TintAndShade = 0, Weight = xlThin
    End With
```

Full Code:

```
rownbrMA_Inflight = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                                     'Set the Management Action row count
row_ptr = 31                                                                                                'Set starting row on home page for new table values
For i = 8 To rownbrMA_Inflight                                                                                    'Not sure of the reason for this

If DataSourceWorksheet.Range("C" & i).Value = "Open" Then                                                   'Only copy items with status as "Open"
InputWorksheet.Rows(row_ptr).Insert Shift:=xlDown                                                        'Select the row_ptr and insert a new row with formating from above
AddStr = "MA_Inflight!" & "$F$" & CStr(i)                                                               ' String to be added is the Cell value for the hyperlink
   With InputWorksheet                                                                                  ' Set the worksheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A" & row_ptr), Address:="", SubAddress:=AddStr, TextToDisplay:=DataSourceWorksheet.Range("O" & i).Value
    End With                                                                                                ' End Hyperlink function
    '------------------------------------                                                                   '
InputWorksheet.Range("B" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("H" & i).Value                        ' Set the 6 week due date
InputWorksheet.Range("C" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("I" & i).Value                        ' Set the MA Close date
InputWorksheet.Range("D" & row_ptr).Value = DataSourceWorksheet.Range("K" & i).Value                        ' Set the Service Assurance Owner
row_ptr = row_ptr + 1                                                                                       ' Last row is row_ptr +1
End If                                                                                                      ' End the set loop
Next i                                                                                                      ' Move to next row
```

Any help is really appreciated thanks.

[Sheet look and Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMOX9.jpg)

Comment: A border is applied to a range, not a worksheet.

Comment: Record a macro while setting the borders you want to - this will give you the idea.

Comment: @FunThomas - I tried that and it only gave me the code for applying it to single ranges which were pre-determined. What my code is doing is generating on the fly till it's run out of data so I don't have those ranges set.

Comment: @SJR - I was applying the border to the worksheet rows or attempting to at least ... I'm not your you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I do understand. There was no reference to a range in your code - you were applying the border directly to the sheet. FunThomas's idea was the right one - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.Range("A" & row_ptr).Borders (xlEdgeTop), LineStyle = xlContinuous, ColorIndex = 0, TintAndShade = 0, Weight = xlThin
```

or

```
.Rows(row_ptr).Borders (xlEdgeTop), LineStyle = xlContinuous, ColorIndex = 0, TintAndShade = 0, Weight = xlThin
```

Comment: tried both and returns _Run-Time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method_

Answer (score 0):

And what about this?

```
With InputSheet.Range("A" & row_ptr).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.ColorIndex = 0
.TintAndShade = 0
.Weight = xlThin
End With
```

or

```
With InputSheet.Rows(row_ptr).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.ColorIndex = 0
.TintAndShade = 0
.Weight = xlThin
End With
```

Comment: putting it within the "With" Statement just comes back with _Run-time error 424: Object Required_

Comment: after the with, so there will be two, one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Change sheet name as required. It's not clear which range to which you want to apply the border.

```
Sub x()

Dim row_ptr As Long

row_ptr = 5

With ActiveSheet
    With .Rows(row_ptr).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With

End Sub
```